# How to not install the specific dependency?

Tags: xcode, dependencies, cocoapods

I'm installing pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel', pod 'Firebase/MLVision', and these pods are installing some dependencies also
I want to not install firebaseCore and FirebaseCoreDiagnostics dependency, how can I restrict these?

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'FirebaseCore' || target.name == 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

I tried this, but it didn't help me.

Comment: I'm not sure it should work, as there are dependencies. MLVision rely on CoreOnly which Rely on Core. There might need really the code from these. What if there is a base class on it and MLVision inherits from it? What if there are utilities in it, and MLVision need to call them?